# How to Install Reporting Services from SQL Server 2016 Express

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2016-express

Trying to test SQL Server 2016 Express and Reporting Services. But I can't select Reporting Services as a feature as described in this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

It quotes the Microsoft homepage: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

> **SQL Server 2016 Express with Advanced Services**
>   Experience the full feature set of SQL Server Express. This package contains the Database Engine, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search features.

How can I activate Reporting Services in SQL Server 2016 Express, or is in NOT part of it?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, **did** you download the "Express with Advanced Services" edition of SQL Server 2016 Express?? If you have, then Reporting Services is part of the installation feature selection. If you don't see that, then you most likely **don't have** the Express with Advanced Services edition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from VS Dev Essentials. I didn't find it anywhere else.Follow the Following Steps :-

Step 1 : Go to this Link https://myprodscussu1.app.vssubscriptions.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1682

Step 2 : Login or Create new Account

Step 3 : Go to Download Section and Search for **'SQL Server 2016 Express'**

Step 4 : Select the **'SQL Server 2016 Express with Service Pack 1
'** from the list and you will see two editions download the one saying **'SQL Server 2016 Express with Advanced Services'**

Sigh... Microsoft never fails to confuse people !!!